# Implementation of Thread-local storage (TLS) in C/C++ (multithreading)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, memory, c++11

I am trying to understand the implementation of `Thread-local storage (TLS)`  type. Available in `C++11` as `thread_local` keyword or in `C` as `__thread` keyword. This [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-Local_Storage) article says:

> Sometimes it is desirable that two threads referring to the same
>   static or global variable are actually referring to different memory
>   locations, thereby making the variable thread-local, a canonical
>   example being the C error code variable **`errno`**.

This is used for making `static` or `global` variables local to the threads, so that the other threads can't access them.

*My question is how are these variables stored in the memory so that it becomes local to a thread ?

After all these are inherently global/static variables, what stops other threads from accessing them ? Are they kept in some special data segment*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TLS is implemented as a data array within each thread object.  Each thread object has its own local copy of the array, and each array is the same size.  When you declare a global/static variable as using TLS, it is associated with an index into those arrays (that is how the compiler/OS knows how many array slots to allocate).  Thus, when you access the variable at runtime, you are really accessing the associated slot in the data array of the thread context that is accessing the variable.

TLS may be a new native feature in C++11, but it has been available in various OS APIs for a long time.

TLS is implemented on Windows using the Win32 API `TlsAlloc()`, `TlsGetValue()`, `TlsSetValue()`, and `TlsFree()` functions.  Here is an overview of how it works:  [Thread Local Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686749.aspx)

Here is an overview of how TLS works on Linux: [ELF Handling For Thread-Local Storage](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf)

Comment: Is it really an array? If different threads are running on different cores and both threads try to access elements of the array, won't the cacheline containing the array elements ping-pong back and forth between the cores?

Comment: It is a per-thread array, not a global array.  One thread cannot access another thread's array, that is what makes it **local** to each thread.  Each thread context has its own copy of the array.

Comment: Is the implementation same for linux? I apologize, I should have mentioned I was asking about linux.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to the Linux documentation for TLS.

Comment: Ok.. so, each threads has a local copy of the array, that means if at `index0` `thread0` has a `TLS` variable `var1`, what will the other threads have at `index0` of their array ? Copy of that same variable `var1` ? Why is it replicated across threads since other threads have no use of that variable ?

Comment: All of the threads will have a `var1` variable located at `index0`, but `thread0` could have a value `1` in its TLS array, `thread1` could have a value of `100` in its TLS array, etc. You are **declaring** the variable once in code, but TLS **allocates** a separate copy of that variable for each thread. Every thread will have its own local `var1` variable in its TLS array.  Whether or not any given thread actually uses `var1` is irrelevant. There is no way to predict that at compile-time. Every thread gets its own copy of the same TLS array structure.

Comment: The `thread_local` TLS is implemented through [load-time TLS rather than through the dynamic `TlsAlloc...` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/thread-local-storage-tls?view=msvc-170). To my understanding it's more akin to ELF TLS, whereas `TlsAlloc` is more like pthreads TLS.