# Make a variable local to a thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, clone

I used clone() to create threads. The problem is that all the global variables are shared. I would like to create variable local to a thread (like a variable called "a" which value is specific to each thread).

Is this doable?

Comment: `man set_thread_area`

Comment: And this is just one of many reasons why global variables should be avoided as far as possible. Use a variable which is local to the function which is the entry point for your thread and pass it down the calling chain as required

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122015/implementation-of-thread-local-storage-tls-in-c-c-multithreading/23122229#23122229

Comment: Keep in mind that ANSI C does not mention threads, so any solution would be platform-specific.